# fetch api, how to round a piece of data that you recieve

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
let input=document.querySelector('#city');
let submit= document.querySelector('#submit');
let output=document.querySelector('#output');


submit.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    let url=`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${input.value}&APPID=758bab291826491e79f93979de2ba255&units=imperial`;
    fetch(url)
            .then(response=> response.json())
            .then(data=>console.log(data.main.temp))  
})
```

The temperature is recieved, but it's in the form of a decimal,  I would like for it to be a whole number, I'm aware of `Math.round()` but not sure when/how to implement it in this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do this:

```
.then(data=>console.log(Math.round(data.main.temp)))
```